# What’s a good substitute for “if that happens”?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

English is not my native language.

I am writing a text where I have to explain some technical stuff and give some examples.

Giving a simple example, I would write something like:

1. To make current flow through air, a huge amount of energy is required. If that happens...."
2. Bob and Mary should not eat more than one piece of cake. If that happens...."
3. An earthquake off the west coast of the USA is a real concern. It is predicted that an earthquake centred on the 'Pythias Oasis' could  reach magnitude 9. If that happens, many major cities may suffer catastrophic damage. [EA; a more natural-sounding example]

My problem here is the "if that happens" part. I don't like the expression "if that happens", which is a precise translation of how I would speak in Portuguese, my native language, but does not sound good in English.

How do I connect a second phrase explaining what happens if the first sentence is true?

"in that case"? What more sophisticated options do I have here?

Comment: Hello, Duck. It's only fair to point out that 'To make current flow through air, a huge amount of energy is required. If that happens... ' does not sound natural; 'To make current flow through air, a huge amount of energy is required. But if that condition is met .... ' construes better.  Also, "Bob should not eat more than one piece of cake. If that _did_ happen ...." sounds more natural. I've added an example (3) which _does_ sound fine to my native ear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "**if so**".
For instance you can say:

> They must not vote for their darlings; If so, that's called discrimination.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! It is appreciated to support your answer with sources.

Answer (score 0):

> "To make current flow through air, a huge amount of energy is required. If that happens... bla bla"

"To make current flow through air, a huge amount of energy is required,[comma] <s>If</s> **when** that happens... bla bla"

As there are many circumstances in which it does happen, you do not need the conditional.